# What is the difference between commandments in ordinance form and general commandments in the Bible?

Tags: commandments

> Having abolished in his flesh the enmity, even the law of **commandments** *contained* **in ordinances**; for to make in himself of twain one new man, so making peace; Ephesians 2:15 KJV

What is the difference between commandments and commandments in ordinance form in the Bible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "commandments" is broad, and includes "ordinances."  But the word "ordinances" is used in a specific manner throughout the Bible, and is narrower in scope.

For example, looking at every occurrence of the word throughout the book of Exodus which also contains the Ten Commandments, we can readily see its pattern of usage.

| Reference | Text |
| --- | --- |
| Exodus 12:14 | And this day shall be unto you for a memorial; and ye shall keep it a feast to the LORD throughout your generations; ye shall keep it a feast by an **ordinance** for ever. |
| Exodus 12:17 | And ye shall observe the feast of unleavened bread; for in this selfsame day have I brought your armies out of the land of Egypt: therefore shall ye observe this day in your generations by an **ordinance** for ever. |
| Exodus 12:24 | And ye shall observe this thing for an **ordinance** to thee and to thy sons for ever. |
| Exodus 12:43 | And the LORD said unto Moses and Aaron, This is the **ordinance** of the passover: There shall no stranger eat thereof: |
| Exodus 13:10 | Thou shalt therefore keep this **ordinance** in his season from year to year. |
| Exodus 15:25 | And he cried unto the LORD; and the LORD showed him a tree, which when he had cast into the waters, the waters were made sweet: there he made for them a statute and an **ordinance**, and there he proved them, |
| Exodus 18:20 | And thou shalt teach them **ordinances** and laws, and shalt show them the way wherein they must walk, and the work that they must do. |

The word "ordinance" is applied to the ceremonial feasts and observances associated with them.  In later passages, we see it also applied to offerings and to priestly duties.

These ordinances were no longer in effect once their types had been met, and fulfilled, in the sacrifice of Christ, their great Antitype--which is why Paul tells us these ordinances had been abolished.